# mongoDB: possible to use "text search" within arrays?

Tags: mongodb, text-search

I want to "text search" within an array in mongoDB.  I want use "text search" for  a document field (which is an array of strings).  I want to be able to get:

```
1. either the array's index
2. either the full string contained by the array at that index
```

of where the "text" was located.

I tried with `$indexOfArray` but it's getting me nowhere, even if I'm using the aggregation framework.

Any clues??

Comment: Chances are you are asking about [regex](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/). "text search" is an index - a light version of elastic search. It works with whole documents, not individual fields.

Comment: @AlexBlex ok, so even if "text search" is searching the whole document, it is not possible to identify the field where the result was found?

Comment: No. Have you read https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/text-search/?

Comment: @AlexBlex Yes, but I thought there was another way to do it, because there's always another way :D